# PHP Image Resize and Expand Placeholder (Transparent)

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I'm trying to resize down a vertical transparent png image, and make the placeholder be square (transparent background).

[image: Sample Image]

As result, I get transparent image but black on the left and right of placeholder (black-transparent-black). Please help to get all area of placeholder be transparent, thank you.

```
$info = getimagesize($source);
$imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

switch ($imgtype) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $src_image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
        break;
    default:
        die('Invalid image type.');
}

$new_w = 300;
$new_h = 300;

$src_x = 0;
$src_y = 0;
$src_w = imagesx($src_image);
$src_h = imagesy($src_image);

$dst_h = round($new_h);
$dst_w = round(($dst_h / $src_h) * $src_w);
$dst_y = 0;
$dst_x = ($new_w - $dst_w) / 2;

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
$alphacolor = imagecolorallocate($dst_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($dst_image, $alphacolor);

imagealphablending($dst_image, false);
imagesavealpha($dst_image, true);

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);

imagepng($dst_image, $destination, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get it working by:

- Using `imagecolorallocatealpha` instead of `imagecolorallocate`
- Using `imagefilledrectangle` instead of `imagecolortransparent`
- Setting the blending mode to false, and the save alpha channel flag to true before I do the imagecolorallocate().

**Working Code**:

```
$info = getimagesize($source);
$imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

switch ($imgtype) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $src_image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
        break;
    default:
        die('Invalid image type.');
}

$src_x = 0;
$src_y = 0;
$src_w = imagesx($src_image);
$src_h = imagesy($src_image);

$dst_h = round($new_h);
$dst_w = round(($dst_h / $src_h) * $src_w);
$dst_y = 0;
$dst_x = ($new_w - $dst_w) / 2;

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);

imagealphablending($dst_image, false);
imagesavealpha($dst_image, true);

$alphacolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($dst_image, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $alphacolor);

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);

imagepng($dst_image, $destination, 0);
```